# I did the 1:3 propensity matching but the turnout shows 1:2.7 ratio, but the SMD results are very ideal, is this correct?

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching, matchit

I was trying to match two groups with n1 = 181 and n2 = 39. Because the regular 1:1 or 1:2 matching cannot produce the ideal SMD results, I changed to 1:3 with caliper = 0.2. The results shows good now (most of the SMD < 0.1) but it turns out that the matched samples are n1 = 95 and n2 = 35. I can understand there are some drop-outs in n2. Some values in n2 cannot find the match within the caliper in n1 so they are dropped. But the ratio becomes 1:2.7 right now, which is not the 1:3 I entered at the beginning. This confused me that how R did this matching? I have attached my code below:

```
set.seed(1000)
match_obj <- matchit(cabg_indication_new ~ age + gender + dm + dialysis + htn + copd + bav + pvd + cvd + previous_cabg + previous_mi + afib + reop, data = project2, method = "nearest", distance ="glm", ratio = 3, caliper = 0.2, replace = FALSE)

summary(match_obj, un = FALSE)
```

Here is the results I got in console:

```
Sample Sizes:
              Control Treated
All             181.       39
Matched (ESS)    87.5      35
Matched          95.       35
Unmatched        86.        4
Discarded         0.        0
```

Anyone has any explanation on this? Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 7):

4 of your n2 units could not find any matches and were dropped, but some of the remaining units could only find 1 or 2 matches. That's perfectly fine and there is nothing that says all units must have exactly 3 matches in order to be validly included in the matched sample. It become critical to include the matching weights in the final analysis, though, as explained in the `MatchIt` [vignette](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html) on estimating effects.